# Runtime Error : both arguments to matmul need to be at least 1d but they are 0d and 2d

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

This is the code I have written, I have tried modifying here and there and have always gotten the same error. As I am a beginner to PyTorch, I am just trying things out to see if machine learning will work on a linear dataset. So, with random, I initialized a dataset. Then, made a single linear neural network. Then, train the neural network on the linear data. Nevertheless, I have an error stating that matmul expects a 1d data, but then my data is at least 1d but is read as 0d instead.

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import random

class LinearNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LinearNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 1)

    def forward(self, input):
        x = self.fc1(input)
        return x; 

#Generate a Dataset to train on. Just a linear function, and we wanna see if this thing is working 
DataSet = []
grad = random.randint(0,100)
const = random.randint(0,100)
for i in range(0, 1000):
    DataSet.append([i, grad*i + const])

DataSet = torch.tensor(DataSet,dtype = torch.double, requires_grad = True)

#Declare a Linear Network
Net = LinearNetwork()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(Net.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
print(DataSet)
#Train Model 
for i, data in enumerate(DataSet, 0):
    Input, Target = data
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    Output = Net(Input)
    loss = criterion(Output, Target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

print("Gradient of the Function is : " + str(grad))
print("Constant Value of the Function is : " + str(const))
print("Learned Gradient and Constant : " + list(Net.parameters()))
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two errors in your code, first regarding shapes, second regarding `dtypes`. BTW. Please use `snake_case` for variables (e.g. `my_dataset`, `net`) and `CamelCase` for classes as it's a common Python convention.

### Shape error

This one lies here:

```
for i, data in enumerate(DataSet, 0):
    input, target = data
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = net(input)
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

When you print `input.shape` you get `torch.Size([])` which is a `0d` tensor. Matrix multiplication needs `1d` tensor so you should `unsqueeze` it so it has this dimension. Change above `output = net(input)` to:

```
output = net(input.unsqueeze(dim=0))
```

### `dtype` error

Here:

```
DataSet = torch.tensor(DataSet,dtype = torch.double, requires_grad = True)
```

You create tensor of `torch.double` type while your neural network is (by default) of type `torch.float`. The latter is usually used as that's enough numerical precision and saves memory. So instead of the above you should do:

```
DataSet = torch.tensor(DataSet,dtype = torch.float, requires_grad = True)
```

### Shape again

Coming back to shapes, neural networks should operate on **at least** two dimensions: `(batch, features)`. In your case `batch=1` and `features=1`, so it should be unsqueezed once more (and i advise you to try your code using batches).